# Sending multipart form data by WSO2 EI version 6.6 to a Rest API

Tags: wso2, multipartform-data, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I need some help here. I'm trying to send a multipart form data to a rest API by WSO2 EI (version 6.6). I'm following this https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/PayloadFactory+Mediator#PayloadFactoryMediator-Example6:UploadingafiletoanHTTPendpointviaamultipartrequest

It sends a file to the API with a success message as a result however the file is corrupted and we cannot open it. I had tried to send both PDF and PNG with the same issue. When I open the corrupted pdf file with notepad++, I can see base 64 code inside it. So I tried to decode the string before sending it to the API with *base64Decode(string encoded value)* but still, the PDF is corrupted. Is there any suggestion for this?
I used to work with ESB 5.0.0 but that version couldn't send the multipart because of missing boundary issue so I had to upgrade to a newer version. I may miss something here, can you please help me? thanks in advance.

My configuration is here:

````
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <enrich>
                <source clone="true" type="body"/>
                <target property="originalBody" type="property"/>
            </enrich>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="multipart/form-data"/>
            <property expression="fn:base64Decode(get-property('originalBody'))" name="content" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <root xmlns="">
                        <ModuleReference>DD</ModuleReference>
                        <FormattedAccount>002.2020.00160735.001</FormattedAccount>
                        <ExternalDocumentType>$1</ExternalDocumentType>
                        <Description>$2</Description>
                        <FileUpload xmlns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd/form-data" filename="$3">$4</FileUpload>
                        <Filename>$5</Filename>
                    </root>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg value="1"/>
                    <arg value="test4"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$trp:FILE_NAME"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:content"/>
                    <arg value="test4.pdf"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Bearer ****"/>
            <call blocking="true">
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="POST" uri-template="http://XXXXX:XX/api/api/v2/recordmanagement/attachments"/>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC" name="Status2"/>

        </inSequence>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///C:/WSO2/test/</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/octet-stream</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">DELETE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*\..*</parameter>
    <description/>
</proxy>```
````

Comment: Could you try specifying the content-type and charset for the file in the payload factory mediator as in the example? 
E.g.: <file xmlns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd/form-data" charset="US-ASCII" content-type="text/plain" filename="$3" name="file1">$4</file>

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion, I did try that at the beginning but the result was the same. I've removed them to see if any difference.

Comment: How you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the content will be shown as base64 encoded when it is sending the binary content of the file. Can you try defining the **multipart/form-data messageType** property after the payload factory mediator? (And remove the configurations related to decoding)

```html
<property name="messageType" value="multipart/form-data" scope="axis2"/>
```

Refer [this](https://medium.com/wso2-enterprise-integrator-wso2-dev-studio-wso2/construct-and-send-multipart-form-data-using-wso2-ei-5cd548d095ee) for more information.

Comment: Hi Prabushi, Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried that (added multipart/form-data as a message type after payload factory and removed the decoding function) but the same result. It has sent the file to the API and got the success response back but when I check the file their, I cannot open it because the content is just base64 encoded. I have tried it with PDF and PNG.

Comment: How you fixed it?

Comment: I couldn't fix it. I had to do it by writing custom code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. Setting the below property in the mediation before sending the file to the endpoint, fixed my issue.

```
<property name="DECODE_MULTIPART_DATA" value="true" scope="axis2" type="BOOLEAN" />
```

The property will remove the base64 encoding done on the multi-part files by the EI.